# Nested Selects Or JOINS?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a snippet from my stored Proc

```
SELECT  NULL AS StoryID
      , AlbumID
      , CAST(NULL as varchar) AS StoryTitle
      , AlbumName
      , (SELECT URL FROM AlbumPictures AS AlbumPictures_3 WHERE (AlbumID = Albums.AlbumID) AND (AlbumCover = 'True')) AS AlbumCover
      , Votes
      , CAST(NULL as Int) AS PictureId
      , 'albums' AS tableName
      , (SELECT NestedAlbums.AlbumID FROM NestedAlbums WHERE (AlbumID = Albums.AlbumID)) AS Flag
INTO #Results2
FROM Albums WHERE AlbumID IN (SELECT StringVal FROM funcListToTableInt(@whereAlbumID))
```

I have used nested selects in my Query above. I am curious to know whether `Nested Selects` are better than `LEFT/Right JOINS` OR should i use `JOINS`?

Table Albums:

[image]

Table NestedAlbums:

[image]

Comment: Better? For what? Readability? Performance? Something else?

Comment: The query planner may rewrite your nested selects as a join anyway. With SQL server it should be really easy to tell by using the client to view the query plan.

Comment: Try both ways, look at the query plans (real ones), check the statistics and those will tell you.

Comment: @user1593175 the performance is equivalent. They're all compiled and cached too to further increase performance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799.aspx see this link to profile your plan @user1593175

Comment: if the performance is equivalent, and they both give the same result, then why are you even spending any time on this?

Comment: [mre] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general writing this an explicit `OUTER JOIN` would be better.

SQL Server will probably need to add an Assert to the plan with the sub query version that verifies the sub query only returns at most one row (unless this is guaranteed by a unique index). This can limit the possible transformations available. See [Scalar Subqueries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/09/27/774107.aspx) for more about this.

Also (though not relevant to the example in your question as both sub queries are different) writing as an explicit `JOIN` allows you to use multiple columns from the joined table with one lookup whereas using separate similar subqueries would not (SQL Server has no logic to detect the common sub expressions).

**Edit:**

Following discussion in comments something like

```
SELECT NULL                      AS StoryID,
       A.AlbumID,
       CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(30)) AS StoryTitle,
       A.AlbumName,
       AP.URL                    AS AlbumCover,
       A.Votes,
       CAST(NULL AS INT)         AS PictureId,
       'albums'                  AS tableName,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM   NestedAlbums NA
                      WHERE  NA.AlbumID = A.AlbumID
                             AND ( AccountId = @AccountId )) THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END                       AS Flag
INTO   #Results2
FROM   Albums A
       LEFT OUTER JOIN AlbumPictures AP
         ON ( AP.AlbumID = A.AlbumID )
            AND ( AP.AlbumCover = 'True' )
WHERE  A.AlbumID IN (SELECT StringVal
                     FROM   funcListToTableInt(@whereAlbumID))
```

You may notice this still has a sub query in the `SELECT` list but `CASE ... EXISTS` [will be implemented efficiently as a semi join](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/23/715306.aspx).

At the moment your query assumes that at most one matching row per album will be returned from `AlbumPictures` and would error out if this assumption is not true. This changes the semantics in that no error will be returned and you would get multiple rows with the various `URL`s. If you didn't want that to happen you would need to define which `URL` to use and add a `GROUP BY`

Comment: Sorry. I am new to this.Kindly explain. How to do an EXPLICIT `OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @user1593175 - Please add table definitions to your question including any unique constraints.

Comment: @user1593175 **explicit joins** use an `ON` clause to associate the join condition, while **implicit joins** use a `WHERE` clause.  Explicit joins more clearly identify how the tables relate to each other.

Comment: @user1593175 - So `AlbumId` is not the primary key of `NestedAlbums`? Do you have a unique constraint on it? If not what should happen if the same Album appears more than once? Similarly in the table `AlbumPictures` is there a unique constraint guaranteeing that for a particular `AlbumID` there will be at most one record where `AlbumCover = 'True'`? Your query at the moment assumes that both can return only one row is either one or the other or both enforced?

Comment: `Sno` is `IDENTITY` in `NestedAlbums` . In `AlbumPictures ` `PictureID` is `IDENTITY`. Similarly i have `IDENTITY` column in all the tables.

Comment: @user1593175 - Are you expecting that a single album can ever appear more than once in `NestedAlbums` or would that be an error if it was to occur?

Comment: Yes a single album can appear more than once but the corresponding AccountID would be different. In other words an user can Nest an album only once.

Comment: @user1593175 - Your current subquery doesn't filter by AccountId so would raise an error in that case.

Comment: Ok. I just spotted that my second Nested statement is wrong. it should be `SELECT NestedAlbums.AlbumID FROM NestedAlbums WHERE (AlbumID = Albums.AlbumID) AND (AccountID=UserAccounts.AccountID) INNER JOIN UserAccounts ON Albums.AccountID = UserAccounts.AccountID`

Comment: That should be `ON NestedAlbums.AccountID = UserAccounts.AccountID` presumably?

Comment: And you would still need a filter on `UserAccounts` for a specific `UserId` I assume?

Comment: Instead of returning `AlbumID` as output. Can we have `True` if `AlbumID` is found and `False` if `AlbumID` is not found.

Comment: "And you would still need a filter on UserAccounts for a specific UserId I assume?" What do you mean here?

Answer (score 4):

The first difference is, **the `FROM` clause governs initial cardinality of the results**.

In your case, the results will have one row per row in Album. Scalar subqueries in the `SELECT` clause cannot change this. If a subquery happens to return multiple rows, SQL Server will throw an exception. It will never add to the results.

When you move this logical join to the `FROM` clause, you **redefine your initial cardinality**. It is no longer one row per row in Album, but one row per row in `Album LEFT OUTER JOIN AblumPictures ON...` etc. If that yields multiple rows per row in Album, SQL Server will *not* throw an exception as it did for the subselect. Rather, it will add rows to the results.

So in this regard, the subquery does a better job expressing intent, and a better job proactively protecting you from data that violates that intent: "give me one row per Album, and for each album, include the URL for here, the nested ID from there" etc.

**HOWEVER**, functionally speaking, there is a huge drawback: scalar subqueries cannot return whole tuples. You've gone through all this work to write the subquery, SQL Server has gone through all this work to execute it, and now you are limited to this one single scalar return value! Sometimes that's fine, but sometimes you need more. When you need more, you need the `FROM` clause.

The closest `FROM`-clause equivalent to a scalar subquery is not `OUTER JOIN`, but rather the wondrous **`OUTER APPLY`**. `OUTER APPLY` *is not* a scalar expression: it return whole tuples, and any number of rows.

First approximation:

```
SELECT Albums.*, AlbumPictures.URL, NestedAlbums.AlbumID
FROM Albums
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP (1) * FROM AlbumPictures
  WHERE (AlbumID = Albums.AlbumID) AND (AlbumCover = 'True')
  ) AlbumPictures
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP (1) * FROM NestedAlbums 
  WHERE (AlbumID = Albums.AlbumID)
  ) NestedAlbums 
WHERE Albums.AlbumID IN (SELECT StringVal FROM funcListToTableInt(@whereAlbumID))
```

So, by virtue of `TOP (1)`, Albums still governs the initial cardinality of the results. However, we now have access to *all* the columns from the related tables, and this is awesome.

Then, **if** we are confident that `TOP (1)` is not necessary--*that by virtue of keys and indexes the subquery can only ever return one row*--then we can rewrite using a simpler form:

```
SELECT Albums.*, AlbumPictures.URL, NestedAlbums.AlbumID
FROM Albums
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT * FROM AlbumPictures
  WHERE (AlbumID = Albums.AlbumID) AND (AlbumCover = 'True')
  ) AlbumPictures
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT * FROM NestedAlbums 
  WHERE (AlbumID = Albums.AlbumID)
  ) NestedAlbums 
WHERE Albums.AlbumID IN (SELECT StringVal FROM funcListToTableInt(@whereAlbumID))
```

Which is now logically equivalent to `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT Albums.*, AlbumPictures.URL, NestedAlbums.AlbumID
FROM Albums
LEFT OUTER JOIN AlbumPictures 
  ON AlbumPictures.AlbumID = Albums.AlbumID 
 AND AlbumPictures.AlbumCover = 'True'
LEFT OUTER JOIN NestedAlbums 
  ON NestedAlbums.AlbumID = Albums.AlbumID
WHERE Albums.AlbumID IN (SELECT StringVal FROM funcListToTableInt(@whereAlbumID))
```

And there you have it. Which is better? Well, whatever you do, please keep it simple.

**PERFORMANCE WISE**, generally, there is not a whole heck of a lot of difference between the forms. You can compare execution plans side-by-side for your particular tables and indexes. It's a good learning experience to see how SQL Server rewrites logically equivalent queries. I'd expect to see identical plans for `OUTER APPLY` (w/o `TOP (1)`) and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated.+1.I have accepted @Martin Smith's answer, otherwise would have accepted yours.Sorry.

Comment: np, just practicing my exposition on random questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess query based on Martin's suggestion of using an OUTER JOIN.  I believe when he said an "explicit" join, he was referring to just choosing that technique and not a technical type of join.  The query below assumes that you will only ever get back one row From the NestedAlbums and AlbumCover tables when searching for a single Album ID - if this is not true, you will get "duplicate rows" and will have to add some more conditions to one of the join clauses to remove them.  This query also assumes that AlbumCover is in the Albums table.  If not, you would have to change the text `a.AlbumCover` to `ac.AlbumCover`

```
SELECT  NULL AS StoryID
      , a.AlbumID
      , CAST(NULL as varchar) AS StoryTitle
      , a.AlbumName
      , ac.URL AS AlbumCover
      , a.Votes
      , CAST(NULL as Int) AS PictureId
      , 'albums' AS tableName
      , na.AlbumID AS Flag
INTO #Results2
FROM Albums a
LEFT OUTER JOIN NestedAlbums na ON a.AlbumID = na.AlbumID
LEFT OUTER JOIN AlbumCover ac ON a.AlbumID = ac.AlbumID AND a.AlbumCover = 'True'
WHERE a.AlbumID IN (SELECT StringVal FROM funcListToTableInt(@whereAlbumID))
```

This query takes the results from Albums, and includes any rows in NestedAlbums that have a matching AlbumID, and also any rows that have a matching AlbumID in the AlbumCover table (but only if the AlbumCover field in Albums is "True" for that row).  Because we've chosen LEFT OUTER JOIN as our operator, if either NestedAlbums or AlbumCover does not have matching rows, SQL Server will return NULL for those fields, but the rows will be returned by the query anyway.  If the joins had been INNER JOIN, then if there were not matching rows in the joined tables, the row from the main table would be filtered out also.

Comment: By explicit I meant that the subquery version will likely show up in the execution plan as an outer join anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For my money, queries written using joins instead of nested selects are "better" because they are easier for people to read and understand (think maintenance, support, future modification, etc.) All the table joining logic is in one place (the `from` clause), and all the columns being returned are in one other place (`select` clause), it just makes it easier to figure out what's going on.

Others have pointed out that there may or may not be perfomance hits executing the query (+1 to @Martin Smith, as usual, for pointing out obscure-but-very-relevant detail), and those answers are what you're looking for here... but take a minute or two to consider the poor developer in the future who has to figure out what the code that's been dumped on them is actually trying to do. After all, it might be you...

Answer (score 0):

In your case both approaches will be almost the same, if you consider performance. ( Considering you have well indexed tables in your data base)

JOIN is easier to use and efficient if too many JOIN are required.
JOIN may create duplicate data while joining, but Nested queries will not.

But finally the performance will be based on the amount and the organization of the data you have. You can use SQL performance monitor tools for validating based on your data.