# SQL Server MAX & MIN from 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by

The Max/Min select below works fine but I want to also join to a Table #3 on EntityCode (i.e. provide the EntityName)

However, I am uncertain whether a nested select or multiple joins is the route:

```
SELECT
    Orders2Buy.EntityCode,
    MAX (Orders2Buy.Bid),
    MIN (Orders2Sell.Ask)
FROM
    Orders2Buy INNER JOIN Orders2Sell ON Orders2Buy.EntityCode = Orders2Sell.EntityCode
GROUP BY
    Orders2Buy.EntityCode)
```

-------COMBINED WITH-------------------

```
SELECT 
    Entities.EntityName 
FROM 
    Entities 
WHERE 
    Entities.EntityCode = Orders2Buy.EntityCode;
```

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184268/nested-selects-or-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal join would be fine i think.

```
SELECT
    Orders2Buy.EntityCode,
    Entities.EntityName,
    MAX (Orders2Buy.Bid) Bid,
    MIN (Orders2Sell.Ask) Ask
FROM
    Orders2Buy 
        INNER JOIN Orders2Sell ON Orders2Buy.EntityCode = Orders2Sell.EntityCode
        INNER JOIN Entities on Entities.EntityCode = Orders2Buy.EntityCode
GROUP BY
    Orders2Buy.EntityCode, Entities.EntityName
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know to put in the second Group By so could not get it to work.  

FWIW I (theoretically) don't understand why the second clause is  necessary if you have an easy to understand answer.

Comment: This is a SQL rule. And it make sense if you think about it. If you want to do an aggregate, you have to aggregate values based on a common thing which could be a single field or a group of fields. Otherwise SQL doesn't know how to aggregate things together.

The result of MAX(Orders2Buy.Bid) GROUP BY Orders2Buy.EntityCode will give you only the maximum Bid based on a consolidated EntityCode.